# Get variable outside while loop shell script

Tags: shell

I would like the get the content of variable outside the while loop using shell script

For example:

::

```
count = 5
while [ @count -gt 0]; do
a=3
b=4
if ( a > b)
 result = "UP"
else
 result = "DOWN"
fi
count=$[ $count - 1]
done

echo $result
```

`$result` appears empty every time!

I just want the content of result outside the loop.

Can anyone help on this issue! I know that the variable inseide the loop is executed in sub-shell, but I tried several tips and doesn't works!

Thanks in avdance

Comment: `count=$((count - 1))`, but since `a` and `b` never change -- the `if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]` (or `(( a > b ))` )  never changes either... and `@count` should be `"$count` -- and you need a space between `0]` did you lose the shell syntax book?

Comment: @CarlosH : Please fix at least the syntax errors, before posting the code. Also, you need to be more clear about what shell you are using: Your tag says 'POSIX shell', but you are using `$[...]`, which is a (already obsolete) bash construct.

Answer (score 2):

Wow you have a huge number of syntax errors in your short script. I have detailed them in the comments below as well as adjusted where the variables are declared to make the loop do something, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

count=5     ## no spaces aroung " = "
a=3         ## a & b never change in loop
b=4

while [ "$count" -gt 0 ]; do    ## always quote variables in [ .. ], spaces required
    if ((a > b)); then          ## there are two ((..)) in arithmetic comparison
        result="UP"             ## NO spaces around " = "
    else
        result="DOWN"           ## ditto
    fi
    printf "%d %s\n" "$count" "$result"  ## some output helps
    count=$((count - 1))        ## use arithmetic ((..)), no $ required inside
    ((a++))                     ## increment a to make it iteresting.
done
```

First, in shell there is no `spaces` allowed around the `'='` sign during assignments. When using `[ .. ]` you must have a space after `[` and before `]`, and always **quote your variables** inside. The quoting isn't required with bash `[[ ... ]]` or with the arithmetic comparison `((..))`.

Every `if` and `elif` must be followed by a `then`. Every `for` or `while` must be followed by a `do`.

When using the arithmetic operator `((..))` (either for an arithmetic operation or comparison) there are two parens required. You can also use the increment and decrement operators `++` and `--`, e.g. `((a++))` to increment/decrement values within, but it you are assigning the result you must preceded the opening `((` with the `$`, e.g. `$((count - 1))`

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh count.sh
5 DOWN
4 DOWN
3 UP
2 UP
1 UP
```

I think that accounts for most of the syntax issues. If you have further questions, please drop a comment below.